# Calling async methods from a synchronous context

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm calling a service over HTTP (ultimately using the HttpClient.SendAsync method) from within my code. This code is then called into from a WebAPI controller action. Mostly, it works fine (tests pass) but then when I deploy on say IIS, I experience a deadlock because caller of the async method call has been blocked and the continuation cannot proceed on that thread until it finishes (which it won't).

While I could make most of my methods async I don't feel as if I have a basic understanding of when I'd must do this.

For example, let's say I did make most of my methods async (since they ultimately call other async service methods) how would I then invoke the first async method of my program if I built say a message loop where I want some control of the degree of parallelism?

Since the HttpClient doesn't have any synchronous methods, what can I safely presume to do if I have an abstraction that isn't `async` aware? I've read about the `ConfigureAwait(false)` but I don't really understand what it does. It's strange to me that it's set after the async invocation. To me that feels as if a race waiting to happen... however unlikely...

WebAPI example:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
  var userContext = contextService.GetUserContext(); // <-- synchronous
  return ...
}

// Some IUserContextService implementation
public IUserContext GetUserContext()
{
  var httpClient = new HttpClient();
  var result = httpClient.GetAsync(...).Result; // <-- I really don't care if this is asynchronous or not
  return new HttpUserContext(result);
}
```

Message loop example:

```
var mq = new MessageQueue();
// we then run say 8 tasks that do this
for (;;)
{
  var m = mq.Get();
  var c = GetCommand(m);
  c.InvokeAsync().Wait();
  m.Delete();
}
```

When you have a message loop that allow things to happen in parallel and you have asynchronous methods, there's a opportunity to minimize latency. Basically, what I want to accomplish in this instance is to minimize latency and idle time. Though I'm actually unsure as to how to invoke into the command that's associated with the message that arrives off the queue.

To be more specific, if the **command invocation needs to do service requests there's going to be latency** in the invocation that could be used to get the next message. Stuff like that. I can totally do this simply by wrapping up things in queues and coordinating this myself but I'd like to see this work with just some async/await stuff.

Comment: using `async/await` is "infectious" if you want to use it, you need to use it all the way down your call stack, you can't (or at least should not) do it only "half way". Please edit your question to show how you are invoking your async methods currently. Also Async and parallel, while related, are not the same thing. Can you explain more about what you mean when you said *"...if I built say a message loop where I want some control of the degree of parallelism"*

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I get that but that's also impractical. Every existing code base is not async aware as of today. Need some middle ground to break the water with...

Comment: Yes it is impractical, changing frameworks (and changing from a sync style to a async style is a framework change) usually require large re-writes of code. But if you only do it half way all of the work arounds to do it require extra resources to be taken up by the server and you end up with the fact that you where getting a higher maximum capacity when you just left it sync.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm well aware of the benefits of doing so, that does not make the problem go away. I can live with some bottlenecks for now, there's always a day after tomorrow to keep improving.

Comment: I still don't understand how you are using your message queue in your WebApi code. What you want is very doable, but we need to understand what you are trying to do in order to show you how to correct it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The message loop is completely unrelated to anything WebApi. For all intent and purposes of this discussion it's a console application that just pulls messages from somewhere... The challenge that I feel that I have with the message loop is balancing parallelism and throughput. Simply outsourcing that task to the TPL doesn't feel very smart (I'm quite certain that I'd have more parallelism than intentional in that case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I appreciate the insight from community members it's always difficult to express the intent of what I'm trying to do but tremendously helpful to get advice about circumstances surrounding the problem. With that, I eventually arrived that the following code.

```
public class AsyncOperatingContext
{
  struct Continuation
  {
    private readonly SendOrPostCallback d;
    private readonly object state;

    public Continuation(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
      this.d = d;
      this.state = state;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
      d(state);
    }
  }

  class BlockingSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
  {
    readonly BlockingCollection<Continuation> _workQueue;

    public BlockingSynchronizationContext(BlockingCollection<Continuation> workQueue)
    {
      _workQueue = workQueue;
    }

    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
      _workQueue.TryAdd(new Continuation(d, state));
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Gets the recommended max degree of parallelism. (Your main program message loop could use this value.)
  /// </summary>
  public static int MaxDegreeOfParallelism { get { return Environment.ProcessorCount; } }

  #region Helper methods

  /// <summary>
  /// Run an async task. This method will block execution (and use the calling thread as a worker thread) until the async task has completed.
  /// </summary>
  public static T Run<T>(Func<Task<T>> main, int degreeOfParallelism = 1)
  {
    var asyncOperatingContext = new AsyncOperatingContext();
    asyncOperatingContext.DegreeOfParallelism = degreeOfParallelism;
    return asyncOperatingContext.RunMain(main);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Run an async task. This method will block execution (and use the calling thread as a worker thread) until the async task has completed.
  /// </summary>
  public static void Run(Func<Task> main, int degreeOfParallelism = 1)
  {
    var asyncOperatingContext = new AsyncOperatingContext();
    asyncOperatingContext.DegreeOfParallelism = degreeOfParallelism;
    asyncOperatingContext.RunMain(main);
  }

  #endregion

  private readonly BlockingCollection<Continuation> _workQueue;

  public int DegreeOfParallelism { get; set; }

  public AsyncOperatingContext()
  {
    _workQueue = new BlockingCollection<Continuation>();
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Initialize the current thread's SynchronizationContext so that work is scheduled to run through this AsyncOperatingContext.
  /// </summary>
  protected void InitializeSynchronizationContext()
  {
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new BlockingSynchronizationContext(_workQueue));
  }

  protected void RunMessageLoop()
  {
    while (!_workQueue.IsCompleted)
    {
      Continuation continuation;
      if (_workQueue.TryTake(out continuation, Timeout.Infinite))
      {
        continuation.Run();
      }
    }
  }

  protected T RunMain<T>(Func<Task<T>> main)
  {
    var degreeOfParallelism = DegreeOfParallelism;
    if (!((1 <= degreeOfParallelism) & (degreeOfParallelism <= 5000))) // sanity check
    {
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("DegreeOfParallelism must be between 1 and 5000.", "DegreeOfParallelism");
    }
    var currentSynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    InitializeSynchronizationContext(); // must set SynchronizationContext before main() task is scheduled
    var mainTask = main(); // schedule "main" task
    mainTask.ContinueWith(task => _workQueue.CompleteAdding());
    // for single threading we don't need worker threads so we don't use any
    // otherwise (for increased parallelism) we simply launch X worker threads
    if (degreeOfParallelism > 1)
    {
      for (int i = 1; i < degreeOfParallelism; i++)
      {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => {
          // do we really need to restore the SynchronizationContext here as well?
          InitializeSynchronizationContext();
          RunMessageLoop();
        });
      }
    }
    RunMessageLoop();
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(currentSynchronizationContext); // restore
    return mainTask.Result;
  }

  protected void RunMain(Func<Task> main)
  {
    // The return value doesn't matter here
    RunMain(async () => { await main(); return 0; });
  }
}
```

This class is complete and it does a couple of things that I found difficult to grasp.

As general advice you should allow the TAP (task-based asynchronous) pattern to propagate through your code. This may imply quite a bit of refactoring (or redesign). Ideally you should be allowed to break this up into pieces and make progress as you work towards to overall goal of making your program more asynchronous.

Something that's inherently dangerous to do is to call asynchronous code callously in an synchronous fashion. By this we mean invoking the `Wait` or `Result` methods. These can lead to deadlocks. One way to work around something like that is to use the `AsyncOperatingContext.Run` method. It will use the current thread to run a message loop until the asynchronous call is complete. It will swap out whatever `SynchronizationContext` is associated with the current thread temporarily to do so.

> **Note:** I don't know if this is enough, or if you are allowed to swap back the `SynchronizationContext` this way, assuming that you can, this should work. I've already been bitten by the ASP.NET deadlock issue and this could possibly function as a workaround.

Lastly, I found myself asking the question, what is the corresponding equivalent of `Main(string[])` in an `async` context? Turns out that's the message loop.

What I've found is that there are two things that make out this `async` machinery.

`SynchronizationContext.Post` and the message loop. In my `AsyncOperatingContext` I provide a very simple message loop:

```
protected void RunMessageLoop()
{
  while (!_workQueue.IsCompleted)
  {
    Continuation continuation;
    if (_workQueue.TryTake(out continuation, Timeout.Infinite))
    {
      continuation.Run();
    }
  }
}
```

My `SynchronizationContext.Post` thus becomes:

```
public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
{
  _workQueue.TryAdd(new Continuation(d, state));
}
```

And our entry point, basically the equivalent of an `async` main from synchronous context (simplified version from original source):

```
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new BlockingSynchronizationContext(_workQueue));
var mainTask = main(); // schedule "main" task
mainTask.ContinueWith(task => _workQueue.CompleteAdding());
RunMessageLoop();
return mainTask.Result;
```

All of this is costly and we can't just go replace calls to `async` methods with this but it does allow us to rather quickly create the facilities required to keep writing `async` code where needed without having to deal with the whole program. It's also very clear from this implementation where the worker threads go and how the impact concurrency of your program.

I look at this and think to myself, yeap, that's how Node.js does it. Though JavaScript does not have this nice async/await language support that C# currently does.

As an added bonus, I have complete control of the degree of parallelism, and if I want, I can run my `async` tasks completely single threaded. Though, If I do so and call `Wait` or `Result` on any task, it will deadlock the program because it will block the only message loop available.

Comment: This approach might make sense if you have to use objects requiring thread affinity (e.g., because they use TLS). Otherwise, I don't see why you'd use this inside an ASP.NET controller method, you'd only  hurt scalability. There's no concurrent code processing the same request anyway, a thread switch after `await` doesn't make the code run in parallel. In case with Node.js, thread affinity is required because JavaScript is inherently single-threaded, it doesn't allow switching threads. In case with C# and ASP.NET, you just need to use `async` "all the way down", without `.Wait`/`.Result`.

Comment: Moreover, you'll find a very similar code to what you've done at Stephen Toub's ["Await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx). This part is especially relevant: *"...Is it a problem then that using async like this in a console app might end up running continuations on ThreadPool threads?.."*

Comment: I generally avoid setting a `SynchronizationContext` on thread pool threads, but if you do, be sure to remove it when you're done with the thread. Also, some parts of ASP.NET (e.g., MVC child actions) assume that the current SyncCtx is an AspNetSynchronizationContext, so this approach doesn't work in all scenarios. You might want to consider using [a task scheduler like this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair(v=vs.110).aspx) if you're 100% sure you want to *parallelize* on ASP.NET (the majority of the time, that's a mistake).

Comment: This doesn't portray to ASP.NET, I know I did talk about the deadlock situation that did occur in a ASP.NET controller but it isn't the sole purpose of why I did this. The only reason I currently have for using the `AsyncOperatingContext` inside a ASP.NET application is to call asynchrnous code in a synchrnous fashion, i.e. block until the `async` call is complete (without risking deadlock) for that `Wait()`/`Result` won't work. The only reason I'd do that is to not have to refactor/redesign all my code in one go. That not practical (even if it's the *ultimate* solution).

Comment: @Noseratio I should also add that this program isn't the only program that will be running on the machine, it part of a suite of programs that will be running on the machine orchestrating events and to that end (even if there's more performant ways to implement this) until I've *asyncified* everything the ability to control the pressure we put on the machine is more important that squeezing a bit here and there. I'm perfectly comfortable with sacrificing some performance to be able to move forward with other work.

Comment: @Noseratio Thanks for the link to Stephen's post, it's very much so what I ended up doing, good read from someone who really knows this stuff. I did not read it though, prior to coming up with this `AsyncOperatingContext` maybe I can improve it somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

> While I could make most of my methods async I don't feel as if I have a basic understanding of when I'd must do this.

Start at the lowest level. It sounds like you've already got a start, but if you're looking for more at the lowest level, then the rule of thumb is anything I/O-based should be made `async` (e.g., `HttpClient`).

Then it's a matter of repeating the `async` infection. You want to use async methods, so you call them with `await`. So that method must be `async`. So all of its callers must use `await`, so they must also be `async`, etc.

> how would I then invoke the first async method of my program if I built say a message loop where I want some control of the degree of parallelism?

It's easiest to put the framework in charge of this. E.g., you can just return a `Task<T>` from a WebAPI action, and the framework understands that. Similarly, UI applications have a message loop built-in that `async` will work naturally with.

If you have a situation where the framework doesn't understand `Task` or have a built-in message loop (usually a Console application or a Win32 service), you can use the [`AsyncContext` type in my `AsyncEx` library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext). `AsyncContext` just installs a "main loop" (that is compatible with `async`) onto the current thread.

> Since the HttpClient doesn't have any synchronous methods, what can I safely presume to do if I have an abstraction that isn't async aware?

The correct approach is to change the abstraction. Do not attempt to block on asynchronous code; I describe that [common deadlock scenario](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) in detail on my blog.

You change the abstraction by making it `async`-friendly. For example, change `IUserContext IUserContextService.GetUserContext()` to `Task<IUserContext> IUserContextService.GetUserContextAsync()`.

> I've read about the ConfigureAwait(false) but I don't really understand what it does. It's strange to me that it's set after the async invocation.

You may find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful. I won't say much more about `ConfigureAwait` in this answer because I think it's not directly applicable to a good solution for this question (but I'm not saying it's bad; it actually *should* be used unless you *can't* use it).

Just bear in mind that `async` is an operator with precedence rules and all that. It feels magical at first, but it's really not so much. This code:

```
var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

is exactly the same as this code:

```
var asyncOperation = httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
var result = await asyncOperation;
```

There are usually no race conditions in `async` code because - even though the method is *asynchronous* - it is also *sequential*. The method can be paused at an `await`, and it will not be resumed until that `await` completes.

> When you have a message loop that allow things to happen in parallel and you have asynchronous methods, there's a opportunity to minimize latency.

This is the second time you've mentioned a "message loop" "in parallel", but I think what you actually want is to have multiple (asynchronous) consumers working off the same queue, correct? That's easy enough to do with `async` (note that there is just a single message loop on a single thread in this example; when everything is async, that's usually all you need):

```
await tasks.WhenAll(ConsumerAsync(), ConsumerAsync(), ConsumerAsync());

async Task ConsumerAsync()
{
  for (;;) // TODO: consider a CancellationToken for orderly shutdown
  {
    var m = await mq.ReceiveAsync();
    var c = GetCommand(m);
    await c.InvokeAsync();
    m.Delete();
  }
}

// Extension method
public static Task<Message> ReceiveAsync(this MessageQueue mq)
{
  return Task<Message>.Factory.FromAsync(mq.BeginReceive, mq.EndReceive, null);
}
```

You'd probably also be interested in [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Dataflow is a library that understands and works well with `async` code, and has nice parallel options built-in.

Comment: I've read some of the material you've blogged about, it's good stuff but a lot to wrap ones head around. My predicament, is that I understand concurrency rather well but `async` somewhat hides the lower level details that I'm used to having control over. Now, I think that's a good thing but it also means that there are new things accommodate and adapt to. Thanks for the elaborate answer.

Comment: As you're learning `async`, just keep in mind that it is about asynchronous programming, not multithreading (two *different* kinds of concurrency). So, if you're used to `IAsyncResult`, it'll feel quite natural; but if you're used to `Thread` and `BackgroundWorker`, it'll feel unusually magical.

Comment: It's the implementation of async in the .NET Framework that I wish to understand so I can better utilize it. Not the computer science part. That I pretty much have covered.