# calling async methods from sync service layer boundary

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

This may have been answered somewhere on the web but I've looked at lots of the examples and I still can't figure it out.

I have a sync based service layer boundary (e.g. "ProcessOrder" method). Within this method it performs various functions, a couple of which have async overloads and it makes sense to use these as they wrap I/O bound functions.

However, my confusion is two-fold. From what I've read:

- async code should be "async all the way down"
- async marked methods should not return void - this is an edge case for event handlers and
  doesn't handle bubbling up exceptions

So, with example code such as below (NB: _publisher is wrapper for Azure QueueClient that has Async Send methods):

```
public void ProcessOrder()
{
    // other stuff...

    _publisher.PublishAsync(new ItemOrderedEvent()
    {
        MessageId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        IsDurable = true,
    }).Wait();
}
```

Doesn't seem to fit the "async all the way down" rule, and there are warnings about deadlocks etc. on the web due to thread pool exhaustion at high loads about this pattern, but code such as:

```
public async void ProcessOrder()
{
    // other stuff...

   await  _publisher.PublishAsync(new ItemOrderedEvent()
    {
        MessageId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        IsDurable = true,
    });
}
```

Breaks the "async marked methods should not return void" rule and will not handle exceptions as, from my understanding, there is no Task context to bubble them back from the async method. NB: This is a service boundary - the calling code may be UI, in response to an MSMQ message, a web service call etc. so I do not want "implementation" of the service call to leak higher up. In the current context, IMO, it makes sense for this to be a sync call only.

The publisher method is defined as:

```
public async Task PublishAsync(IMessageBusMessage message)
{
    // do azure stuff
    var _queue = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "ItemOrdered");
    await _queue.SendAsync(message);
}
```

So my question is... how the heck do you make use of legitimate I/O bound async methods within a sync based architecture? The typical answer seems to be "you can't" (as suggested by this [Calling async methods from a synchronous context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022573/calling-async-methods-from-a-synchronous-context)) but then I must be missing something as it seems perfectly reasonable to want to offload I/O bound work and let the current thread do some other work, in contexts that are not UI based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it seems perfectly reasonable to want to offload I/O bound work and
>   let the current thread do some other work, in contexts that are not UI
>   based.

If this is a non-UI thread, and you do have some other work to do *while* your IO-bound operation is pending, then nothing prevents your from doing so inside your synchronous method:

```
public void ProcessOrder()
{
    // other stuff...

    // initiate the IO-bound operation
    var task = _publisher.PublishAsync(new ItemOrderedEvent() {});
    {
        MessageId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        IsDurable = true,
    }); // do not call .Wait() here

    // do your work
    for (var i = i; i < 100; i++)
        DoWorkItem(i);

    // work is done, wait for the result of the IO-bound operation
    task.Wait(); 
}
```

This might make sense if you cannot afford re-factoring all of your code to use "async all the way down" philosophy (which may be time-consuming, but almost always possible).

Comment: Doesn't this cause the same "exhausted threads" problem I'm fearful off from my original .Wait() solution? i.e. so many threads are submitted processing Publish that there are none available to handle the callback to Wait?

Comment: @GrahamB, there's no `callback` to `Wait`. You've already got the thread blocked with waiting, so it is available a-priori. It's a different question if you may have enough of `ThreadPool` threads to handle the completion of `PublishAsync` (and signal an event that would release your waiting thread). Yes, that might be a problem, but you can't have the best of both worlds. You have to go "async all the way down" to reduce the chance of `ThreadPool` starvation. I.e., don't block the thread with `Wait()` and use callbacks instead (i.e. `await`).

Answer (score 3):

> NB: This is a service boundary - the calling code may be UI, in response to an MSMQ message, a web service call etc. so I do not want "implementation" of the service call to leak higher up. In the current context, IMO, it makes sense for this to be a sync call only.

Actually, you've got that backwards. :)

Consider this method declaration:

```
public void ProcessOrder();
```

That is most definitely synchronous. If it does anything asynchronous, it'll be blocking, so it'll act like it's synchronous. The only way it could be interpreted as asynchronous is if it took some kind of callback or was paired with an event or something like that, and in that case it would unambiguously be asynchronous.

Now consider this method declaration:

```
public Task ProcessOrderAsync();
```

That is most likely asynchronous. But it *could* possibly be synchronous, if it returns a task that is already completed. Await has a ["fast path" shortcut](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2011/04/15/async-ctp-refresh-design-changes.aspx) that it uses to handle this scenario, and actually treat it as synchronous. Caching is one example where this is used in practice; a cache hit is synchronous.

So, if you want to abstract away the asynchrony of your implementation, then you should use *asynchronous* method declarations.

Note: a `Task`-returning method is a (possibly-)asynchronous declaration, whereas `async` is an implementation detail.

That said, [there are a variety of ways to "wrap" asynchronous code into a synchronous API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx), but every one of them has drawbacks and none of them works in every scenario. It's best to keep your APIs telling the truth: if any implementation may be asynchronous, then the method declaration should be asynchronous.

Comment: I'm glad you responded as it was your articles that made me realise wrapping async/sync was a bad idea. However the basic premise of my misunderstandings still remains I think. I want to use Async to let my main sync based thread (what is running ProcessOrder) do something else whilst it's waiting for the I/O of the publish method. Therefore I'm using async for internal service boundary performance reasons, not to allow a potential caller to use my code in an async fashion. It's this, what I think should be a common reason for aasync, that I can't get my head around the way to implement it.

Comment: As a follow up, is this http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext&referringTitle=AsyncContextThread what I'm after? This seems to wrap an async method in a context that can be used in a non-UI based process.

Comment: I still think async all the way is a better solution (your API should tell the truth). However, `AsyncContext` would work. So would @Noseratio's answer if you always use `ConfigureAwait(false)` within `PublishAsync`.

Comment: ok thanks very much. I guess it's semantics as to whether my API tells the truth or not. IMO i'm using async for internal scalablity reasons, not for anything else, therefore there is nothing to tell the outside world, but thanks for your feedback. Now I know I'm not missing something obvious I'll look at the AsyncContext wrapper further.

Answer (score 1):

> how the heck do you make use of legitimate I/O bound async methods within a sync based architecture?

You can't have your cake and eat it too. You either go async, and then you have to "go async all the way", or you go sync and then you block.

You can, and this is bad practice, spin another thread and do the blocking IO there, but that will be wasting a thread just to block so you can do more work in the meanwhile.

```
public void ProcessOrder()
{
  // other stuff...

  Task.Run(async () => await _publisher.PublishAsync(new ItemOrderedEvent()
  {
    MessageId = Guid.NewGuid(),
    IsDurable = true,
  }).ContinueWith((Task task) => //do continuation if you need);
```

}

But spinning off such a thread loose is terribly bad practice.

I would either go async all the way if possible, or use a blocking sync call (call Result Or Wait as you did in your original post)

```
public async Task ProcessOrder()
{
  // other stuff...

 await _publisher.PublishAsync(new ItemOrderedEvent()
 {
    MessageId = Guid.NewGuid(),
    IsDurable = true,
 });
}
```